# SQL - fill nulls in a single column with previous non-null value

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table that looks like this:

```
   DATE        COST   ID    TYPE    UNITS_SOLD  COST_DATE SALE_DATE
   ------    ------   ---- -------- ----------- --------- ---------
   01/02/15  2000     1      GAME       NULL    01/02/15   NULL
   01/03/15  NULL     1      GAME       3       NULL       01/03/15
   01/04/15  NULL     1      GAME       6       NULL       01/04/15
   02/04/15  3000     2      BOOK       NULL    02/04/15   NULL
   02/05/15  NULL     2      BOOK       5       NULL       02/05/15
```

I would like to replace the nulls in the cost_date column with the most recent non-null cost_date for a given ID and type.

Ideally, the resulting table would look like this:

```
   DATE        COST   ID    TYPE    UNITS_SOLD  COST_DATE SALE_DATE
   ------    ------   ---- -------- ----------- --------- ---------
   01/02/15  2000     1      GAME       NULL    01/02/15   NULL
   01/03/15  NULL     1      GAME       3       01/02/15   01/03/15
   01/04/15  NULL     1      GAME       6       01/02/15   01/04/15
   02/04/15  3000     2      BOOK       NULL    02/04/15   NULL
   02/05/15  NULL     2      BOOK       5       02/04/15   02/05/15
```

I am currently attempting to do a self join and coalesce cost_date on itself. Any ideas?

Comment: why dont put your current query?  So we know what you have tried and what problem you have

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE YourTable Y1
SET COST_DATE = (SELECT COALESCE(MAX(COST_DATE), @YourDefaultDATE)
                 FROM YourTable Y2
                 WHERE Y2.DATE < Y1.DATE)
WHERE COST_DATE IS NULL
```

**NOTE** you still can have `NULL` if doesnt found a previous date, so you need `COALESCE` and a `default value`

**REVISED:** When you say repalce, I tought you want an `UPDATE`

```
SELECT (SELECT COALESCE(MAX(COST_DATE), @YourDefaultDATE)
        FROM YourTable Y2
        WHERE Y2.DATE < Y1.DATE) as COST_DATE 
FROM YourTable Y1
WHERE COST_DATE IS NULL
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this without doing an UPDATE to keep the integrity of the data in the database?

Comment: @DataBeast Check now

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like that:

```
update table a
set COST_DATE = (
select max(COST_DATE) from table b
where b.COST_DATE is not null
and b.id = a.id
and b.type = a.type
and b.date <= a.date
)
where COST_DATE is null
```

Comment: I think `MAX()` ignore `NULL` so the `b.COST_DATE is not null` is probably not necesary

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza yep, its redundant